# How can I test for a filled area?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

What I want to do is detect if any block of a wall is broken. At the moment, I have 1 command block for 1 block of the wall. This means I need several command blocks to see if any block of the wall is broken and I was wondering if there is anyway to do that with 1 command block instead? I'm in 1.12.

Comment: You can use the `AffectedBlocks` of a clone command to count how many blocks are in the wall. If it is less than what you expect, something was broken.

Answer (score 1):

You can build a copy of it (or clone it) in a secure area. Then you get the lowest and the highest x, y and z coordinates of the wall (that form a box around it) and the lowest x, y and z coordinate of your copy. Then you do:

```
/testforblocks <x y z low> <x y z high> <x y z of copy>
```

A comparator will be on/a conditional command block will be executed, if the two areas are the same.

You can see the formal syntax and a more detailed explanation of the command [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#testforblocks) ([archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Commands/stats&oldid=1167489)).

Comment: Oh wow I didn't even realise there was a testforblocks command XD I've just been using testforblock. Thanks for the reply!